# Filter all in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-scope

I am a beginner in AngularJS and I have an issue, here my code:

```
$scope.categories = [{
    "id": 506,
    "name": "test"
}, {
    "id": 510,
    "name": "aaa"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bbb"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ccc"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "eee"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "fff"
}];

$scope.contents = [{
    "id": 0,
    "categoryId": 506,
    "title": "test1"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "categoryId": 506,
    "title": "test2"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "categoryId": 506,
    "title": "test3"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "categoryId": 1,
    "title": "test4"
}];

<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="category" ng-model="cc" ng-value="" checked/>all
    </label>

    <label ng-repeat="categoryItem in categories" ng-init="i= $parent">
        <input type="radio" name="category" ng-model="i.cc" ng-value="{{categoryItem.id}}" />{{categoryItem.id}}
    </label>
</div>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="content in contents | filter:{categoryId: cc||undefined}">
        <h3>id:{{content.categoryId}}</h3>
        <p>{{content.title}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to be able to see all the items by selecting radio, in addition, I would like to first of them was always selected. Like right now it not work and I really don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues/changes:-

- Do not use interpolation with ng-value, i.e `ng-value="{{categoryItem.id}}"` should be `ng-value="categoryItem.id"`. ng-value can just be an expression or a scope property that will be assigned to the ng-model.
- Do not use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) or `$parent` on the view, they are not desired patterns to use. [Instead use dot rule](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14049480%2Fwhat-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs&ei=NWS4VI_wIqfksATfooL4BA&usg=AFQjCNHJLGSHJVwlNkIK1Z9xS5H_rC5ErQ&sig2=k1OvsA-Wy3zzSObs7EWVYw&bvm=bv.83829542,d.cWc). define the filter object in the controller and set the property categoryId on the filterobject as the ng-model for the radio buttons.

  `<input type="radio" name="category" 
        ng-model="categoryFilter.categoryId" ng-value="categoryItem.id" />{{categoryItem.id}}`
- Just clear out the filter by setting `categoryFilter` to `{}` on click of `all` filter, and use ng-checked.

  all
- Just use the filter with the ng-repeat as follows:

  ```
   <li ng-repeat="content in contents | filter:categoryFilter">
  ```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.categoryFilter = {};
  $scope.categories = [{
    "id": 506,
    "name": "test"
  }, {
    "id": 510,
    "name": "aaa"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bbb"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ccc"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "eee"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "fff"
  }];
  $scope.clearFilter = function() {
    $scope.categoryFilter = {};
  }
  $scope.contents = [{
    "id": 0,
    "categoryId": 506,
    "title": "test1"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "categoryId": 506,
    "title": "test2"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "categoryId": 506,
    "title": "test3"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "categoryId": 1,
    "title": "test4"
  }];


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="category1" ng-click="categoryFilter={}" ng-checked="!categoryFilter.categoryId" />all
    </label>

    <label ng-repeat="categoryItem in categories">
      <input type="radio" name="category" ng-model="categoryFilter.categoryId" ng-value="categoryItem.id" />{{categoryItem.id}}
    </label>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="content in contents | filter:categoryFilter">
      <h3>id:{{content.categoryId}}</h3>
      <p>{{content.title}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. All it is now clear for me

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its good to start over with your code, if you cant seem to find it.
Isn't there some filter help on the angularjs website?

[Tut 9, Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

Comment: I have tried several times since the beginning, in different ways. This seems to be the best, otherwise it does not work to select all.